# Updating Image File Execution Options with reg command, why is both 64but and 32bit keys updated?

Tags: windows, registry

I'm updating Image File Execution Options with reg command

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe" /v "Debugger" /t REG_SZ /d "\"c:\windows\Notepad2.exe\" /z" /f
```

And both 64bit keys and 32bit keys are updated, why?

[image]

And if delete the wow6432node key with `regedit`, the 64bit key is gone as well.

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: because `Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options` is [shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys) key begin from *Windows 7*. the `\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options` is symboliclink to `\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/W9joyzH.png

Comment: In case the symlink target in RbMm's comment isn't obvious, the Windows registry API maps the predefined pseudo-handle `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (i.e. HKLM) on the local system to a real handle for "\REGISTRY\MACHINE". The "REGISTRY" and "MACHINE" keys exist in memory only; they're not loaded from a registry hive on disk, unlike the "SOFTWARE" subkey.